# Unable to access an IP address via WiFi hotspot on Android Pie

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, hotspot

I'm trying to access a device (a monitoring gadget that serves a web page) that is at a public IP address.

For example: http://80.0.22.20:8465/

This works fine, in a web browser, using my mac (macbook retina mid 2012 running Mojave 10.14.4) connected to a "standard" WiFi network. (a router connected to a fixed line)

This works fine, in the web browser, on my phone. (Moto G6, Android 9 Pie)

When I connect the mac to the phone WiFi hotspot this doesn't work. I can access regular webpages (e.g. superuser.com) that go via DNS lookup. I cannot access IP addresses directly.

Trying to ping 80.0.22.20:8465 gets me an unknown host.

Spotify also thinks I'm offline.

It is not just the 80.0.22.20 device that has issues. None of these widgets are accessible. I can only get to web pages via DNS.

Any idea where to start looking please?

The provider is EE (in the UK), their "adult content" locks etc are off, and there is no restriction o tethering.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you tether your phone? I'm with EE and from Windows via a tethered android your link works fine.

Comment: It is possible that your macbook does not connect because it knows you are on a data plan and wants to preserve bandwidth. I know for a fact that on windows, Microsoft Outlook will not allow a connection either.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

It was a handset issue. What exactly I am unsure, but factory resetting the device and setting it up without a Google "Work Profile" appears to have cured this one.

Comment: I had a similar issue - only IPv6 addresses could be reached via hotspot, not IPv4 addresses - which actually sounds like the same problem.  I think it was resolved by changing Preferred Network Type to 3G then back to 4G, though I did fiddle with some other settings.  The issue had been consistently present for months (but not always obvious because access via DNS usually worked).  Provider was also EE UK, but may be just a coincidence.